# how to import the zip file in cypress

Tags: cypress, cypress-file-upload

```
it("tick on the project folder in sideNavigation",() => {
    cy.get(":nth-child(5) > :nth-child(1) > .bp3-menu-item > .eccgui-icon").click();
    cy.get("[data-test-id=empty-workspace-create-project-btn]").click();
    cy.get("[data-test-id=project-import-link]").click();
     const filepath = 'xxx.zip'
    cy.get('.uppy-Root').attachFile(filepath);
    cy.get('[data-test-id="startImportProjectBtn"]').click()
```

});***here i am adding the zip folder in cypress but the zip folder is not adding in the drag n drop box***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attachFile()` command sets up the data (you can check file is attached in dev-tools), but it may not trigger events required to perform upload.

Try adding a `change` event trigger or an `input` event trigger.

```js
.attachFile(filepath).trigger('change');
```